# Making a counter incremental in a for-each loop (along with the position value)

Tags: javascript, xslt-1.0

Here is a snippet from a XSL script that applies a template:

```
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TFGW/BibleReadingItem/Readers/Reader | AYFM/StudentItem/Students/Student"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
```

The template itself assigns the `position` value as the `id` attribute of the `div`:

```
<xsl:template match="Student | Reader">
    <xsl:if test="self::Student">
        <hr/>
    </xsl:if>
  
    <div class="student-slip">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>containter-student-slip</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </div>

    <button class="copy-button">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>button</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
            <xsl:text>CopyToClipboard('containter-student-slip</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Translations/msa:Translations/msa:*[local-name() = $LangCode]/msa:ButtonText"/>
    </button>
</xsl:template>
```

As you can see, I also have a button (which uses javascript). That function is: `CopyToClipboard`. That is defined as:

```
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
    clearSelection();
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
        range.select().createTextRange();
        document.execCommand("copy");
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("]]><xsl:value-of select="$Translations/msa:Translations/msa:*[local-name() = $LangCode]/msa:AlertText"/><![CDATA[")
    }
}
 ]]>
```

I appreciate that this is not a full working sample. The issue I am having is that the primary `for-each` loop. When it applies the templates for each meeting it is restarting the counter - I understand why it is doing that. But the problem is that if the user has the second meeting on view and clicks the button, that it selects the item with that id from the very first week.

Is there a way that we can somehow have a sequential increment? Eg, the first loop iteration starts at 1 (or whatever) and the next loop iteration starts where the first left off?

---

I thought I would do a test that simply tries to display a ID value using `generate-id` but I can't get it to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
                    <p>Meeting</p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="TFGW/BibleReadingItem/Readers/Reader | AYFM/StudentItem/Students/Student"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Student | Reader">
        <xsl:variable name="vID">#{generate-id(.)}</xsl:variable>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vID"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All I get it:

```
Meeting

{generate-id(.)}#{generate-id(.)}

{generate-id(.)}#{generate-id(.)}

{generate-id(.)}#{generate-id(.)}

Meeting

{generate-id(.)}#{generate-id(.)}

{generate-id(.)}#{generate-id(.)}

{generate-id(.)}#{generate-id(.)}

{generate-id(.)}#{generate-id(.)}

Etc..
```

Am I using `generate-id` incorrectly?

Comment: This is very difficult, if not impossible, to follow. Please provide a [mcve]. --- Speaking very generally, if you want consecutive numbering that counts outside of the [current node list](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#dt-current-node-list), then you need to use `xsl:number`, not `position()`.

Comment: Or perhaps you just need to use `generate-id()`? Again, hard to tell without seeing the big picture.

Comment: @michael.hor257k At the moment each iteration creates a `div` containers, but because it is using `position()` it is always restarting from the base number. I'll have a look at `xsl:number`.

Comment: But do you really need consecutive numbering? Or do you only need a unique value?

Comment: @michael.hor257k a unique value so that the Java function selects the correct div entry as they will be unique ids.

Comment: Then I believe `generate-id()` would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ok. I do need to use that ID value twice as you can see, once on the div and once with the button. To create the pairing.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I will try this afternoon.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Struggling with `generate-id`. See updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position()` gives you the position of a `AYFM/StudentItem/Students/Student` or `TFGW/BibleReadingItem/Readers/Reader` *within* a `Meeting`. To get the position across all meetings, you can use

```
count(preceding::Reader[parent::Readers/parent::BibleReadingItem/parent::TFGW] |
      preceding::Student[parent::Students/parent::StudentItem/parent::AYFM]) + 1
```

which counts all such students or readers that precede the current one (and adds 1 so that the counter starts with 1, not 0).

(Note that the path expressions inside the `count` specify the ancestors "backwards", compared to the path expressions in the `select`.)

Alternatively, you could use `generate-id()`, but must then write it as

```xml
<xsl:variable name="vID">#<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/></xsl:variable>
```

because you can use "brace notation" only inside an attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get my code working correctly with `generate-id` based on your syntax example. Now all it good. It is simpler than using the numerical counter.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle It's not only simpler. Repeated counting of preceding nodes is grossly inefficient.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I agree 100% with you.